# Changes in cache saved in database before calling Persist()

Tags: acumatica

I have created a new grid with Case classes in Contract Template screen which updates case classes for particular Contract Template. There is a checkbox for every case class in the grid and when I check/Uncheck, RowUpdatedEventHandler is triggered and I am updating the contents of Cache.
I have overridden Persist() to save the contents of the cache in Database. But before Persist() is being called the changes are saved in the database and the cache is cleared.Please, Someone help me with this

```
protected void CRCaseClass_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs 
e)
    {
        CRCaseClass newrow = (CRCaseClass)e.Row;
        CRCaseClass oldrow = (CRCaseClass)e.OldRow;
        ContractTemplate row = contracts.Current;
        CaseContract c = new CaseContract();
        CRCaseClassExt newrow_ext = 
              PXCache<CRCaseClass>.GetExtension<CRCaseClassExt>(newrow);
        CRCaseClassExt oldrow_ext = 
              PXCache<CRCaseClass>.GetExtension<CRCaseClassExt>(oldrow);
        c.CaseClassID = newrow.CaseClassID;
        c.ContractID = row.ContractID;
        c.Active = newrow_ext.Check.Value;
        caseContract.Insert(c);

    }


    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist()
    {

        bool c = caseContract.Cache.IsInsertedUpdatedDeleted;
        CaseContract cc = null;
        IEnumerable cacheRecords = caseContract.Cache.Inserted;
        List<CaseContract> recordsToBePersisted = new List<CaseContract>();

        ContractTemplate row = contracts.Current;
        foreach (CaseContract cr in cacheRecords)
        {
            PXResultset<CaseContract> v = PXSelect<CaseContract, Where<CaseContract.contractID, 
                Equal<Required<ContractTemplate.contractID>>, And<CaseContract.caseClassID,
                Equal<Required<CRCaseClass.caseClassID>>>>>.Select(Base, row.ContractID, cr.CaseClassID);
            if (v.Count != 0 && v.Count == 1)
            {
                cc = v.GetEnumerator().Current;
                cc.Active = cr.Active;

            }
            else if (v.Count == 0)
            {
                cc = new CaseContract();
                cc.CaseClassID = cr.CaseClassID;
                cc.ContractID = cr.ContractID;
                cc.Active = cr.Active;
            }

            else {
                //Error Logic
            }
            recordsToBePersisted.Add(cc);
        }

         //clean all cache
        //insert all values from recordsToBePersisted
        caseContract.Cache.Clear();
        foreach (CaseContract i in recordsToBePersisted) {
            caseContract.Insert(i);
        }
        Base.Persist();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Acumatica way to override virtual methods in BLC extensions is slightly different from what you get used to with the .Net framework. Below is the updated version of your code, that should resolve the issue with empty caches. For more details on this topic, please refer to [the Acumatica Customization Guide](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6fa2a444-17b4-42f9-9e6a-64e85167626a)

```
[PXOverride]
public void Persist(Action del)
{
    bool c = caseContract.Cache.IsInsertedUpdatedDeleted;
    CaseContract cc = null;
    IEnumerable cacheRecords = caseContract.Cache.Inserted;
    List<CaseContract> recordsToBePersisted = new List<CaseContract>();

    ContractTemplate row = contracts.Current;
    foreach (CaseContract cr in cacheRecords)
    {
        PXResultset<CaseContract> v = PXSelect<CaseContract, Where<CaseContract.contractID, 
            Equal<Required<ContractTemplate.contractID>>, And<CaseContract.caseClassID,
            Equal<Required<CRCaseClass.caseClassID>>>>>.Select(Base, row.ContractID, cr.CaseClassID);
        if (v.Count != 0 && v.Count == 1)
        {
            cc = v.GetEnumerator().Current;
            cc.Active = cr.Active;
        }
        else if (v.Count == 0)
        {
            cc = new CaseContract();
            cc.CaseClassID = cr.CaseClassID;
            cc.ContractID = cr.ContractID;
            cc.Active = cr.Active;
        }
        else 
        {
            //Error Logic
        }
        recordsToBePersisted.Add(cc);
    }

    //clean all cache
    //insert all values from recordsToBePersisted
    caseContract.Cache.Clear();
    foreach (CaseContract i in recordsToBePersisted) 
    {
        caseContract.Insert(i);
    }
    del();
}
```